# Date time format UI

Tags: cocoa

My app shows many dates/times and I would like to allow user to create its own format using a friendly interface like the OSX system UI shown in image[image: System Date/time format UI]

I can't find any cocoa or CF API to show a similar panel, if possible I prefer don't re-implement it from the scratch.

Anyone can point me if this panel can be shown from standard API or if exists a ready to use component?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for NSTokenField, though you will need to do some modifications to make it work for your case.

Comment: NSTokenField is necessary for single date element but I hoped to not re-implement the whole panel, every check, drag and drop and so on